# Override class at runtime

Tags: c#-4.0

in C# assembly under my control is a class. I control creating all its instances. How can I override its constructor, all methods and properties at runtime? How can I create an instance of this overriden class?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Why don't you post your code? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It sounds like you want to intercept all calls to the object? Have a look a the Castle Framework and search for interceptor for example.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I would like to catch any exception of the object and make some action instead of catch the exception somewhere else. I need to replace instance of object when specific exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used reflection to create a code and compiled it by *CSharpCodeProvider*.

Answer (score 0):

Look for dependency Injection framework: Unity, Ninject, Castle Windsor framework.